# How to extract an Array from API response

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, api

Hello I am using `https://www.npmjs.com/package/ytfps` package to get the URLs and titles from youtube playlists. The format given as response to `ytfps(url).then(playlist =>{console.log(util.inspect(playlist))}` is the following:

```
{
   title: 'Music Playlist',
   url: 'https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLoXvI0xCls_7WZpfvrqwBNqlnZTMylyTvdo6',
   id: '7WZpfvrqwBNqlnZTMylyTvdo6',
   video_count: 16,
   view_count: 16,
   description: '',
   isUnlisted: false,
   thumbnail_url: 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/jBmkNzfqFZUSW4/hqdefault.jpg',
   author: {
     name: 'Default',
     url: 'https://www.youtube.com/user/gadfgagaq',
     avatar_url: 'https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AKedOLQoEJLXJMV2t3MRgadfqNuhWk46GwnYr7r1DAgnGbsQ=s176-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj'
   },
   videos: [
     {
       title: 'Barei - Say Yay! (Eurovision 2016 Spain)',
       url: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jBmkNzFZUW4',
       id: 'jBmkNzFZUW4',
       length: '3:07',
       milis_length: 187000,
       thumbnail_url: 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/jBmkNzFZUW4/hqdefault.jpg',
       author: [Object]
     },
     {
       title: 'Sound of Silence',
       url: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4S6sT_2gM2o',
       id: '4S6sT_2gM2o',
       length: '3:16',
       milis_length: 196000,
       thumbnail_url: 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/4S6sT_2gM2o/hqdefault.jpg',
       author: [Object]
     },

   ]
}
```

**What I want** is to get  2 arrays one of URLs and the other one of titles, like this:

```
url= [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jBmkNzFZUW4', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4S6sT_2gM2o', and so on... ]
titles =['Barei - Say Yay! (Eurovision 2016 Spain)', 'Sound of Silence', and so on ]
```

So what is the best way to extract those 2 arrays?

Comment: Why do you expect there to be a `.getJSONArray()`? Especially when there is no such thing as a "JSON Array"

Comment: @Andreas So what kind of object is that and how can i filter? I have tried also with JSONObject but it is the same problem

Comment: `playlist.videos` is an array, so... `playlist.videos.reduce(...)`. But because of a comment on one of the answers... -> Add a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try This :

```
let urls = [];
let titles = [];
playlist.videos.forEach(element => {
    urls.push(element.url);
    titles.push(element.title);
 });

 console.log("urls",urls);
 console.log("titles",titles);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can declare two separate arrays, map the videos array on your object and push to those arrays accordingly,

Like:

```
const videoTitle = [];

const videoUrl = [];

playlist.videos.map(v => {
  
    videoTitle.push(v.title)
    videoUrl.push(v.url);
});
```

Comment: And how can I extract that videos array from playlist? because if I try `util.inspect(playlist).videos.map` it tells me `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` which I guess that is because im not getting that array correctly

Answer (score 1):

You need just to iterate videos. Then, for each video, you extract the url and put the result in an urls array. The same for the title, you extract the title and put the result in an titles array.

Something like :

```
const urls = [];
const titles = [];

playlist.videos.forEach(video => {
    urls.push(video.url);
    titles.push(video.title);
});

console.log(urls);
console.log(titles);
```

Comment: I get `Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined` which means that `playlist.videos` doesnt work. How can i extract that videos array?

Comment: I have no problem for my side. Try to execute this full script https://gist.github.com/razafinarivohanania/8ba8e45ac98ed6820fd3723d20f917e3 Normally it will work.